# Illegal valence meaning

Tags: computational-chemistry, cheminformatics

I'm using the [rdkit package](http://rdkit.org/) to process some molecules.
I noticed that when creating a molecule from a SMILES string the library does some syntactic and some semantic checks. This question regards the semantic part (sanitization). (Just in case someone wants to take a look, the checks are described in detail [here](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/greglandrum/4316433#Sanitization)).

In the sanitization process the explicit and implicit valence of all atoms is computed and it fails when atoms have *illegal valence*. I don't really understand what *"illegal valence"* mean in this context. I tried using some compounds with charged atoms to see if they have *"illegal valence"* but they didn't. Examples: `Cc1cc(SCC(=O)c2ccc(Br)cc2)cc(C)[o+]1`, `O=[V]([O-])([O-])[O-]` where the Oxygen in both cases is charged (once positively and once negatively).

- What does *"illegal valence"* mean? Is it just using more electrons than the ones actually available in the atom? e.g. 2 bonds with a hydrogen.
- Furthermore, if the previous is true, I suppose that even combinations that are potentially unstable (in practice) with a lot of charged atoms would still be considered "semantically valid"?

Thanks!

Comment: The positive oxygen charge is tripping your program. I noticed a similar thing happening in ChemDraw online.

Comment: What do you mean by "tripping"?

Comment: Are you able to share the molecules which produced the error? It's difficult to say whether this is a bug in the RDKit or just an incorrect SMILES string. 'Illegal valence' is likely to be a reference to an incorrect number of valence electrons.

Comment: No molecules produced any error. I'm trying to understand when this error is triggered :)